Confine the variables to the real domain in numerical maximization
I'm trying to first obtain the objective function, V[r,k], through integration and then find the optimal r and k that maximize V, all through numerical method. Here is the code:
Clear["Global`*"];
c = 1/10; d = 9/10; q = 1; s = 4;
iF = Hold[1/(6 d (-1 + r)^2 s^2) (3 c ((d  (1 + i))^2  (-3 + q (2 - 4 r) + 5 r) + 2  d  (1 + i)  (k - 2 k r + k (-1 + 2 q) r^2 + s - r s) + k (k (-1 - r + 2 q r) (1 + (-3 + r) r) + 2 (-1 + r) r s)) + (-1 + r) (-2 (d  (1 + i))^3 + 3 (d  (1 + i))^2  (k - k r + s) + k^2 (k (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) - 3 r^2 s) + 3 d ((d  (1 + i))^2 + 2  d  (1 + i)  k  (-1 + r) - 2  d  (1 + i)  s + k (k + k (-3 + r) r + 2 r s))))];
iX = i /. FullSimplify[Solve[i == ReleaseHold[iF], i]][[1]];
v = (1 - r)  x + r  Max[x - k, 0] + r  Min[y, k]; 
V[k_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[If[v - d  (1 + iX) > 0, v - d  (1 + iX), 0]/s^2, {x, (d  (1 + iX) - r*k)/(1 - r), k}, {y, (d  (1 + iX))/r - (1 - r)/r  x, s}] + NIntegrate[If[v - d  (1 + iX) > 0, v - d  (1 + iX), 0]/s^2, {x, k, d  (1 + iX) + r*k}, {y, (d  (1 + iX))/r + k - x/r, s}] + NIntegrate[If[v - d  (1 + iX) > 0, v - d  (1 + iX), 0]/s^2, {x, d  (1 + iX) + r*k, s}, {y, 0, s}];
NMaximize[Piecewise[{{V[k, r], d <= k < 2  d && 1/2 < r <= (d/k)}}], {k, r}] 

When run, the first couple of lines of the error message is this:

The problem seems to lie in the solution for iX which turns out to be
1/4 (47 - 10 k (-1 + r) + (7241 + 20 k (-29 + 5 k (-1 + r)) (-1 + r) - 6400 r)/(449211 - 451200 r - 300 k^2 (-51 + r (124 + 29 r)) + 30 k (3799 + r (-5239 + 3200 r)) + 1000 k^3 (-1 + r (3 + r + r^2)) + \[Sqrt]((-7241 - 20 k (-29 + 5 k (-1 + r)) (-1 + r) + 6400 r)^3 + (449211 - 451200 r + 10 k (-30 k (-51 + r (124 + 29 r)) + 3 (3799 + r (-5239 + 3200 r)) + 100 k^2 (-1 + r (3 + r + r^2))))^2))^(1/3) + (449211 - 451200 r - 300 k^2 (-51 + r (124 + 29 r)) + 30 k (3799 + r (-5239 + 3200 r)) + 1000 k^3 (-1 + r (3 + r + r^2)) + \[Sqrt]((-7241 - 20 k (-29 + 5 k (-1 + r)) (-1 + r) + 6400 r)^3 + (449211 - 451200 r + 10 k (-30 k (-51 + r (124 + 29 r)) + 3 (3799 + r (-5239 + 3200 r)) + 100 k^2 (-1 + r (3 + r + r^2))))^2))^(1/3))

That is, it seems the above expression becomes a complex number with k=0.918621. So I would like to add some condition (or assumption) that confines the range of k (and r?) such that iX is always a real number. I tried adding &&Element[i2AX, Reals] right next to 1/2 < r <= (d/k) in the last line, but it didn't work. Can anyone help please?

I think you need to test your function V before trying to maximize it

@mikado, thanks, can you please let me know how?
